# Passing special character as part of URI parameter

Tags: rest, url, uri, postman

I have to pass a special character ('#') hash as part of my URI parameter while using Postman.

http://localhost:9082/client/rest/Retrieval/listemail?bookID=**#1063**

The below bookID value is not getting passed to the server. Can someone help.

Comment: That's what [URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) is for.  If you want to do it manually (e.g. for Postman), just Google for on on-line URL encoding page.

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4. It worked. Wasn't able to find it :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the built feature of Postman to help you with this. Simply, highlight the part of the URL that you would like to encode and right click.

This will display a context menu with the option to either `Encode` or `Decode` the selected value.

[image: Postman]

Comment: I did it now. Though I also needed it as a general check which Paul mentioned using the URL encoding, but your logic helped the testing for Postman.